# Creating an ERC-681 URI for a custom contract call with array parameter

Tags: eip, erc

ERC-681 URIs can be used for any arbitrary contract transaction as well. Even though there are specifications for data types like address, uint, string etc., there are no specifications for how to encode array type parameters.

Considering the following function on a contract at address: 0xc0ffee254729296a45a3885639AC7E10F9d54979

```
function store(uint256 id, uint256[] calldata values);
```

My instinct to encode this into a ERC-681 URI would be:

```
ethereum:0xc0ffee254729296a45a3885639AC7E10F9d54979/store?uint256=100&uint256[]=[1,2,3]
```

Any clarification on this regard is appreciated.